# How to solve this equation of n-order matrix?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

**Question:**

Let **i** be an n-level identity matrix and **j** be an n-level matrix with all elements of 1.

Let n-order matrix **m** be

$M=\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}k & \lambda & \lambda & \cdots & \lambda \\ \lambda & k & \lambda & \cdots & \lambda \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\ \lambda & \lambda & \lambda & \cdots & k\end{array}\right)$

How to express **m** in the form of x **i** + y **j**, where x and y are coefficients.

**My code:**

When n is a definite positive integer, I can successfully run the code to solve x and y.

For example, `n==5`:

```
Clear["Global`*"];

m = DiagonalMatrix[Table[k - \!\(TraditionalForm\`\[Lambda]\), {5}]] +
   ConstantArray[\!\(TraditionalForm\`\[Lambda]\), {5, 5}]

i = IdentityMatrix[5]

j = ConstantArray[1, {5, 5}]

Reduce[x*i + y*j == m, {x, y}]
```

> $\mathrm{x}=\mathrm{k}-\lambda \operatorname{\& \& } \mathrm{y}==\lambda$

But when n is an uncertain positive integer (just a symbolic variable), the code fails.

```
Clear["Global`*"];

$Assumptions = (m | i | j) \[Element] Matrices[{n, n}];

m[n_Integer?Positive] := 
 DiagonalMatrix[Table[k - \!\(TraditionalForm\`\[Lambda]\), {n}]] + 
  ConstantArray[\!\(TraditionalForm\`\[Lambda]\), {n, n}]

i[n_Integer?Positive] := IdentityMatrix[n];

j[n_Integer?Positive] := ConstantArray[1, {n, n}];

Reduce[x*i[n] + y*j[n] == m[n], {x, y}]
```

> $\left(j[n] \neq 0 \& \& y=\frac{-x i[n]+m[n]}{j[n]}\right)||\left(j[n]=0 \& \& i[n] \neq 0 \& \& x=\frac{m[n]}{i[n]}\right)||(m[n]=0 \& \& j[n]=0 \& \& i[n]=0)$

**I wonder if MMA can solve this problem?**

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```
ident[i_, j_] := KroneckerDelta[i, j]
jmat[i_, j_] := 1
mmat[i_, j_] := (k - \[Lambda])  KroneckerDelta[i, j] + \[Lambda]
```

then:

```
res = Assuming[
 {i \[Element] Integers && j \[Element] Integers},
 Reduce[x ident[i, j] + y jmat[i, j] == mmat[i, j], {x, y}, Reals]
 ]
```

gives me:
[image]

and,

```
FullSimplify[res]
```

gives me
[image]